# Why is there such a high amp-draw for hoist motors?

Tags: motor

I'm currently looking at a 1.2 HP hoist motor and I can't figure out (or maybe I can't accept) what difference in the construction of the motor causes it to draw so much more power.

At 1.2 HP and 110 V, assuming 90% power factor and efficiency, I'd make a quick guess that a motor should draw in the ballpark of 8.5 A.

$$ I = \frac{HP * 746}{V * pf * n} = \frac{1.2 * 746}{110 * 0.9 * 0.9} = 10 A$$

Now, when I'm looking at this [spec sheet](https://www.kito.ca/products/ser/print) (line 5-7), all the 1.2 HP motors draw ***23.9 A***.

---

[image: Hoist motor specifications.]

---

What is causing this increase in amp draw? If I'm more aggressive with my estimate, the pf is probably 0.8 instead of 0.9 but that only increases amperage to 11.3 A. To get close to the amperage listed in the specs the efficiency would be close to 47%. My knowledge is that even lightly loaded motors operate with an efficiency above 70%, maybe that's where my thought process is flawed?

Are hoist motors really this inefficient? Is there a mechanical reason for the increase? Or, is this just a case of the Mondays and I'm overlooking something really obvious.

---

```
Details of the motor from the spec:

Single phase
Totally enclosed fan cooled (TEFC) squirrel cage
Re-connectable Voltage:115/230-1-60
Insulation class B
Hertz: 60
60 minute, H4 rated, fan cooled for demanding applications
```

Comment: Probably the startup/stall current that you'd want to not trip the breaker.  Conversely there used to be a department store notorious for rating their house-brand appliances in horsepower calculated backwards from the stall current, needless to stay it was not meaningful...

Comment: And if it's not stall torque, it's losses in the gearbox.  Particularly if there's a worm gear in there (worm gears are notoriously inefficient, but quite salubriously self-braking -- this goes hand in hand with the inefficiency, so it's not like it's avoidable).

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- that very well could be. They didn't break it out any further (MCA, FLA, or locked) so that could be a solid assumption.

Comment: 90% is wildly optimisitc for efficiency for a motor of that size, 70% would be expected

Comment: @TimWescott -- gears are listed as: "Induction-hardened, durable alloy steel helical and spur gears submersed in an oil bath". Even if you had losses in the gearbox would the motor not draw the same amperage and you'd simply have less lifting power?

Comment: @Neil_UK -- Fair. I'm used to pretty efficient motors. So all-in-all, it sounds like 47% efficiency really *isn't* out of the question?

Comment: aka "Sears Horsepower"

Comment: It's a single phase motor, so best efficiency would be 70%-75%.  42.5% is not impressive, but realistic.

Comment: You can probably expect a low power factor for a motor like this.  Efficiency and power factor are likely somewhere near equal, say about 0.6 each. The motor is likely designed to have a high slip and maximum torque at stall. It is designed to be a hoist motor. It is not going to be like a general-purpose motor.

Comment: @CharlesCowie -- so you're saying that the 24A draw is correctly spec'd as the nominal current? Stall current would be higher yet?

Comment: Yes, I expect that the 24A draw is probably the normal working current. The stall current would be higher, but perhaps not as high as would be expected with a general purpose motor.

Comment: 'squirrel cage'... induction motor power factors are notoriously bad, especially at startup:(